# How do I transform a list of items into groups to predict group ratings in azure machine learning?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm newbie to azure machine learning and I'm trying to build a model that rates groups of items.

My data is a file with a list of items with features (small list - less than 80 items) and I need to make groups (of diferent sizes - groups of 2, 3, 4,... 10 items, for all the possible combinations) so that the model rate those groups (rates from 1 to 10). I also have some group rates to train the model.

I don't know how to transform the items into groups.

Another thing is, I'm not sure which model is the best. From all I gather, I think that a multiclass classification is the most suitable for this problem. Is it?

Thank you in advance and sorry for any grammar error in my text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert various groups as columns. One of the such example is where you have sales for specific day and you need have sales for past days as additional features. Here is the code that does convert rows to columns for having sales for previous days - https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/CustomModule/Generate-Lag-Features-1 - source code for this - https://gist.github.com/nk773/a2ed7cd0ce8020647f5e7711f749b3b5